# How to update timestamp in local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I need to store and update a timestamp in local storage so after one minute the modal will execute each time. I want the modal to appear on refresh only if the time stamp has expired or gone past one minute. One minute duration is just for testing purposes. Goal is to only show a modal once a day to user. Here is what I have so far. It only shows modal on refresh and stores local storage key. But after one minute the modal does not appear on refresh and should.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
          function shouldShowModal() {
              const lastTimestamp = localStorage.getItem("modalTimestamp");
              if (!lastTimestamp) {
                  return true;
              }
              const parsedTimestamp = parseInt(lastTimestamp, 10);
              let expiryLimit = new Date(parsedTimestamp);
              expiryLimit = expiryLimit.setMinutes(expiryLimit.getMinutes() + 1);
              return new Date() > expiryLimit;
          }
    
          if (window.localStorage) {
              const currentUser = '<%= current_user %>';
              const currentTime = new Date($.now());
              if (currentUser && shouldShowModal()) {
                  swal ({
                      icon: 'warning',
                      text: 'Notice text here.',
                      closeOnClickOutside: false,
                      button: 'ok'
                  })
                  localStorage.setItem('modalTimestamp', currentTime);
              }
          }
    }
```

Updated working with @Barmar solution:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
          function shouldShowModal() {
              const lastTimestamp = localStorage.getItem("modalTimestamp");
              if (!lastTimestamp) {
                  return true;
              }
              const parsedTimestamp = parseInt(lastTimestamp, 10);
              let expiryLimit = new Date(parsedTimestamp);
              expiryLimit = expiryLimit.setHours(expiryLimit.getHours() + 24);
              return new Date() > expiryLimit;
          }
    
          if (window.localStorage) {
              const currentUser = '<%= current_user %>';
              const currentTime = new Date();
              if (currentUser && shouldShowModal()) {
                  swal ({
                      icon: 'warning',
                      text: 'Notice text here.',
                      closeOnClickOutside: false,
                      button: 'ok'
                  })
                  localStorage.setItem('modalTimestamp', currentTime.getTime());
              }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Dear OP, you should add updated solution in answer rather than showing solution at the end of answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentTime` is a `Date` object, you need to save the numeric timestamp in local storage. So use

```
localStorage.setItem('modalTimestamp', currentTime.getTime());
```

I also don't see any need to use `$.now()` when setting `currentTime`. `new Date()` defaults to returning the current time.

Comment: Wouldn't you need some kind of timer event if you wanted to check every 60 seconds if the modal should be shown or not?

Comment: @topsail He doesn't want it shown every 60 seconds. He wants it shown if the page is opened more than 60 seconds since the last time.

Comment: And in the real application it will be a day, not a minute -- that's just for testing.